# String in UTC getting converted to EST Instant

Tags: java

I have a date time string with zoning:

```
“2019-07-15 00:00+00:00”
```

When I use the following code, the instant it produces is equivalent to the date time “2019-07-14 20:00:00+00:00”. Why is that? I want the Instant to be equivalent to the time initially given.

```
Instant myInstant = OffsetDateTime.parse(“2019-07-15 00:00+00:00”, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(“uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXXXX”)).toInstant();
```

Comment: Of course _the instant_ is equivalent. That's what an instant means. When it's 8pm for you it's midnight UTC.

Comment: I’m sorry I wasn’t clear enough. The instant it gives me is equivalent to 2019-07-14 20:00:00+00:00.

Comment: Ah. OK, I'll delete my answer.  Might have another look later (dinner wants me).

Comment: What happens if you use `xxx` in your pattern? I note that (1) uppercase `X` uses `Z` for zero/Zulu (although it should be lenient on input) and (2) you've specified the format that includes hour/minute/second, so it might be misinterpreting your `+00:00` as "plus zero minutes, zero seconds" and using the default hour.

Comment: Interesting. So what would the pattern and input string look like?

Comment: `"uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssxxx"` (If that works, try `XXX` and report back. A self-answer describing these differences would be useful.)

Comment: That code (version 3) doesn't run. `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-07-15 00:00+00:00' could not be parsed at index 16`. --- Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). --- Removing `:ss` from pattern makes it run, and gives correct result, so **unable to reproduce**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

### ISO 8601

Replace SPACE with `T`, per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse(
    "2019-07-15 00:00+00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) 
)
.toInstant()
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/x53whn).

> 2019-07-15T00:00:00Z

### Formatting pattern

Or specify a formatting pattern to match your exact input.

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse(
    "2019-07-15 00:00+00:00" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mmxxx" )
)
```

---

## Details

### ISO 8601

Rather than wrestle the formatter, I recommend altering your input string to comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2019-07-15 00:00+00:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

> 2019-07-15T00:00+00:00

Parse as an `OffsetDateTime`. The *java.time* classes use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing/generating text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

> odt.toString(): 2019-07-15T00:00Z

That value is already in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). But if you wish, you can extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) which is always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-07-15T00:00:00Z

### `OffsetDateTime` vs `Instant`

> I want the Instant to be equivalent to the time initially given.

They are equivalent. Both the `odt` & `instant` objects represent the same moment in time, as well as the same moment intended by your string input.

The `Z` on the end means an offset of zero, or UTC itself. The `Z` here is pronounced “Zulu” by tradition. The `Z` is short for `+00:00`.

A `Instant` is always in UTC, while a `OffsetDateTime` object may have any offset, zero or otherwise. Another difference is that `OffsetDateTime` is more flexible in generating strings, able to use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

### Pattern: `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mmxxx`

> `Instant myInstant = OffsetDateTime.parse(“2019-07-15 00:00+00:00”, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(“uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXXXX”)).toInstant();`

I suggest you handle the `DateTimeFormatter` separately.

```
String input = "2019-07-15 00:00+00:00" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mmxxx" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

➥ That formatting pattern above uses `xxx` to parse the `+00:00`. The `x` (or `X`) character is for numeric offsets. Three such letters are for an offset hours-with-minutes along with a COLON character in between (otherwise optional). The lowercase `x` characters are for zeros rather than the `Z` abbreviation. To quote [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'.
>
> … Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "odt.toString(): " + odt ) ;
System.out.println( "instant.toString(): " + instant ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/9W4wrt).

> odt.toString(): 2019-07-15T00:00Z
>
> instant.toString(): 2019-07-15T00:00:00Z